# Как исправить проблему с данными в django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-model

С начала я создал модели

```
class Theme(models.Model):
    theme_name = models.CharField(max_lenght = 20, unique = True)
    
class Info(models.Model):
    theme = models.ForeignKey(Theme, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    info_theme = models.CharField(max_lenght = 20, unique = True)
    info_desc = models.TextField(default = "Leage of Leagend information")
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    info = models.ForeignKey(Info, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, unique = True)
    comment_text = models.TextField(default = "comennt")
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

Затем я почти полностью изменил models.py, сделал миграции и когда во views.py пытаюсь написать

```
ivent = Ivent.objects.all()oreder_by('publish_date')
```

И в ivents.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<p>{{ivent.ivent_theme}}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Ничего не выводиться. Вот новые models.py и еще кое какие файлы которые могут пригодиться:

```
from django.db import models

class Theme(models.Model):
    theme_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, unique = True)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.theme_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Тема"
        verbose_name_plural = "Темы"

class Ivent(models.Model):
    theme = models.ForeignKey(Theme, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    ivent_theme = models.CharField(max_length = 20, unique = True)
    ivent_info = models.TextField(default = "Leage of Leagends information")
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ivent_theme

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Ивент"
        verbose_name_plural = "Ивенты"

class Patch(models.Model):
    theme = models.ForeignKey(Theme, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    patch_theme = models.CharField(max_length = 20, unique = True)
    patch_info = models.TextField(default = "Leage of Leagends information")
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patch_theme

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Патч"
        verbose_name_plural = "Патчи"

class Ivent_comment(models.Model):
    info = models.ForeignKey(Ivent, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, unique = True)
    comment_text = models.TextField(default = "comennt")
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Комментарий"
        verbose_name_plural = "Комментарии"

class Patch_comment(models.Model):
    info = models.ForeignKey(Patch, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, unique = True)
    comment_text = models.TextField(default = "comennt")
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Комментарий"
        verbose_name_plural = "Комментарии"
```

setting.py

```
"""
Django settings for lolsite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os, sys 

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'zy8kd9pb2a=-0181jw$ozg7ym75*a-emc!b7ah=0b9$atuq&47'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'lolsite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'lolsite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from home.models import Theme, Ivent, Patch, Ivent_comment, Patch_comment
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404, HttpResponse

def homepage(request):
    themes = Theme.objects.all().order_by('theme_name')

    return render(request, 'home/homepage.html', {'themes': themes})

def ivents(request):
    ivent = Ivent.objects.all().order_by('theme')
    
    return render(request, 'home/ivents.html', {'ivent': ivent})
```

Если понадобятся какие-то файлы, я добавлю.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, правильно будет не `Ivent` а `Event`.

Во вторых, вы неправильно делаете order_by:

> ivent = Ivent.objects.all()oreder_by('publish_date')

а надо:

```py
ivent = Ivent.objects.all().order_by("publish_date")
```

В третьих, вы вообще во вьюхе все правильно передаете? Плюс `Ivent`ы будут переданы как массив, поэтому в темплейте нужно их через for loop рисовать.

Comment: в дополнение сказанному выше. правильно что не выводится. потому что объект QuerySet, который вы в итоге передаете в шаблон, не имеет аттрибута ivent_theme.